# Need an excel formula to count the top five most frequent text strings in a table column without pivot table

Tags: excel

I need an excel formula to count the top five most frequent text strings in a table column without a pivot table. So if I have a column with a,b,b,c,c,c,d,d,d,e,e,f,f,f,f I'd get bcdef as my most frequently used items. I was thinking countif but that won't work my application.

Comment: Create a unique list and do a count for each. Then use large() to get the 5 largest. Then index() with match() to get the names. Posted a similar solution not too long back so you can have a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with Office 365 Excel:

```
=LET(
    rng,A1:A15,
    unq,UNIQUE(rng),
    cnt,COUNTIF(rng,unq),
    srt,SORTBY(unq,cnt,-1),
    INDEX(srt,{1;2;3;4;5},1))
```

[image]